# Android - content appearing underneath toolbar

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a nav drawer to my Android app. I'm new to Android so I'm a little confused. Content is appearing under the toolbar like this: 
[image]

I'm not sure what's going on. In my manifest I set the style as .NoActionBar. Here's my activity code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

</FrameLayout>



<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/home_list_view">

    </ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: There's a closing LinearLayout tag, it's just not showing up

Comment: Is because you have `Toolbar` inside `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Toolbar code from your frame layout and it will work just fine. Also, don't forget to remove the codes from your class.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```